# How does `^` mean in Webpack DevServer Proxy pathRewrite

Tags: javascript, webpack, proxy, configuration, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to understand the [Webpack DevServer Proxy documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy).

My goal is to proxy any paths without .html to the corresponing `.html` file. Examples: `/foo` -> `/foo.html` and `/bar` -> `/bar.html`

I guess, I need to use `pathRewrites`. The documentation example suggests to rewrite the path with `pathRewrite: {'^/api' : ''}`.

The syntax (of the first argument) is not yet clear to me: What is the meaning of the caret (`^`) character? Is it a Regexp? Is the syntax documentet somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

> The dev-server makes use of the powerful http-proxy-middleware
>   package.

that defines

> Object-keys will be used as RegExp to match paths.

-> yes, it's a Regexp. ✅

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to achieve the exact same functionality as you. For the future viewers of this question: http-proxy-middleware **does not support capture groups https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/271 as per now.**

So you are forced to use a custom rewrite function that appends the extension to your path as stated here: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/blob/master/recipes/pathRewrite.md#custom-rewrite-function